# Multiple solutions in answer

Tags: discussion, answers

As a general rule, should there be multiple solutions in a answer or should the poster post multiple answers?

Comment: The system *lets you do that*, this has to be for a reason I suppose.

Comment: Also see this: https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17257/when-to-add-another-answer-instead-of-updating-my-current-one